# Akka http- Request timed out after 10 seconds while waiting for entity data: Consider increasing the timeout for toStrict

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I am using akka http server for file upload as:

```scala
    (path("file" / "upload") & post) {
          formFields("formParams") { formParams =>
            fileUpload("zip") {
              case byteSources =>
                val result = uploadTOS3(formParams, byteSources)
                onSuccess(result){ res =>
                  complete(HttpResponse(entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, res)))
                }
            }
          }
       }
```

akka config:

```
akka.http {
 parsing.max-content-length = 1000m
 parsing.max-to-strict-bytes = 100000m
 server.parsing.max-to-strict-bytes = 100000m
 server.parsing.max-content-length=4096m
 server.request-timeout = 1500 seconds
 server.idle-timeout = 1500 seconds
 client.idle-timeout = 600s
 client.connecting-timeout = 600s
}
```

Versions:

```
val ScalaVersion = "2.13.8"
val AkkaVersion = "2.6.19"
val AkkaHttpVersion = "10.2.9"
```

Getting the error when uploading a file:

```
 akka.http.scaladsl.model.IllegalRequestException: Request timed out after 10 seconds while waiting for entity data: Consider increasing the timeout for toStrict
[info]  at akka.http.scaladsl.model.IllegalRequestException$.apply(ErrorInfo.scala:99)
[info]  at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$toStrictEntity$3$1.applyOrElse(BasicDirectives.scala:404)
[info]  at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$toStrictEntity$3$1.applyOrElse(BasicDirectives.scala:400)
[info]  at scala.util.Failure.recover(Try.scala:233)
[info]  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.run(Promise.scala:487)
[info]  at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)
[info]  at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:100)
[info]  at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
[info]  at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:94)
[info]  at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:100)
[info]  at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:49)
[info]  at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:48)
[info]  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
[info]  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
[info]  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
[info]  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
[info]  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
```

I tried config change like timeout params but does not help.
Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem and here is a fix.

For Strict entity default timeout is 10 seconds. I tried to increse timeout in config file but that does not work so added directly into code:

```
    toStrictEntity(timeout = 60.seconds) { // increse  timeout here 
      (path("file" / "upload") & post) {
          formFields("formParams") { formParams =>
            fileUpload("zip") {
              case byteSources =>
                val result = uploadTOS3(formParams, byteSources)
                onSuccess(result){ res =>
                  complete(HttpResponse(entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, res)))
                }
            }
          }
       }

   }
```

Maybe helpful for others!